# Persisting data from a Symfony 4 form with AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, json-deserialization

I'm using a Symfony Form to modify my "Context" entity and I have a problem to get the data from an ajax request in order to modify my entity. I found another way to do what I need (below) but I'm not using handleRequest :

**ContextController:**

```
    public function share(Request $request, Context $context, UsersRepository $usersRepository)
    {
        $users = $usersRepository->findAll();
        $form = $this->createForm(ShareContextType::class, $context, ['users' => $users]);

        // Envoie du formulaire de partage de contexte en ajax
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('GET')) {
            $template = $this->render('context/share.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ])->getContent();
            $json = json_encode($template);

            return new JsonResponse($json);

        // Requête post avec les id's des utilisateurs pour le partage de context
        } elseif ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $reponse = $request->getContent();
            $json = json_decode($reponse);
            $formArray = [];

            // Ajoute chaque utilisateur aux tableaux d'utilisateurs de ce contexte
            foreach ($json as $userId) {
                $user = $usersRepository->find($userId);
                $context->addUser($user);
                $formArray[] = $user;
            }

            // Si l'utilisateur n'est pas présent dans le tableaux de la requête
            // alors supprime l'utilisateur du tableau du contexte
            foreach ($context->getUsers() as $user) {
                if (!in_array($user, $formArray, true)) {
                    $context->removeUser($user);
                }
            }
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return new JsonResponse(['success' => 'Ok']);
        }
```

**My JS:**

```
    $('#share-context-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        formData = $('#share_context_users').val();
        sendShareContext(formData, $('#context-id').val());
    })

function sendShareContext(formData, contextId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/contextes/' + contextId + '/share',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        async: true,

(...)
```

It's works perfectly. But if I try to do in my JS :

```
$formData = $('#share-context-form').serialize();
```

And get the serialized objects in my Controller to do something like :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
(...)
}
```

It doesn't work, because when I try to get the $request content I actually get something like :

```
$request->getContent() // Output : "share_context%5Busers%5D%5B%5D=25&share_context%5B…en%5D=vrWCjceU9LVGVrSKyMggRdXNNjeG4KTBDLW0HqIh3aQ"
```

I also tried to deserialize it with Symfony's SerializerInterface, doing :

```
$serializer->deserialize($form, ShareContextType::class, 'json');
```

But it doesn't work either.
I'll be appreciate if you have some ideas. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### View

Sounds like you needed `serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()` in your JS. Example:

```
$('#share-context-form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('/contextes/' + $('#context-id').val() + '/share', $(this).serializeArray(), function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        // Success handler
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Fail handler (optional)
    }).always(function() {
        // Finished handler, success or fail
    });

});
```

---

With these kind of submissions you may want to a) validate that the context ID is present, and b) protect against accidental double clicks:

```
var shareContextFormSubmitting = false;

$('#share-context-form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (shareContextFormSubmitting) {
        // Optional: Prevents multiple forms submitting in parallel (blocks double click mistake)
        return false;
    }

    var contentId = $('#context-id').val();
    if (typeof contentId != "number" || isNaN(contentId) || contentId < 1) {
        // Do some alert or whatev because contentId is empty, I'm guessing you expect this to be an integer at least 1
        return false;
    }

    shareContextFormSubmitting = true;
    $.post('/contextes/' + contentId + '/share', $(this).serializeArray(), function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        // Success handler
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Fail handler (optional)
    }).always(function() {
        shareContextFormSubmitting = false;
    });

});
```

### Controller

The problem is also in your controller right here:

```
// Requête post avec les id's des utilisateurs pour le partage de context
} elseif ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $reponse = $request->getContent();
    $json = json_decode($reponse);
    $formArray = [];
```

jQuery's [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) takes a form and prepares a variable for a regular HTTP POST request in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding. (Unrelated: This is why you can't use `serializeArray()` to upload a file field.)

You're trying to read this as if were JSON, but in fact its a string of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". You just need to use Symfony's standard functions for this. I'd suggest updating your controller function as follows:

*I've not got a test for this so some adapting may be required. I also don't speak French so some of the comments and validation errors I've attempted to keep may not make total sense.*

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

public function share(Request $request, Context $context, UsersRepository $usersRepository)
{
    $users = $usersRepository->findAll();
    $form = $this->createForm(ShareContextType::class, $context, ['users' => $users]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Gérer la soumission du formulaire, que ce soit AJAX ou standard
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        // Ajoute chaque utilisateur aux tableaux d'utilisateurs de ce contexte
        $formArray = [];
        $usersField = $form->get('users');
        $usersSubmitted = $usersField->getData();

        if (is_array($usersSubmitted) && count($usersSubmitted) >= 1) {
            foreach ($usersSubmitted as $i => $userId) {
                if (($userId = intval($userId)) < 1) {
                    $usersField->addError(new FormError(sprintf("ID utilisateur %d non valide.", ($i + 1))));
                    continue;
                }

                if (!($user = $usersRepository->find($userId))) {
                    $usersField->addError(new FormError(sprintf("L'utilisateur %d avec l'ID # %d est introuvable..", ($i + 1), $userId)));
                    continue;
                }

                $context->addUser($user);
                $formArray[] = $user;
            }
        } else {
            $usersField->addError(new FormError("Utilisateurs non spécifiés."));
        }

        // Enregistrer uniquement s'il n'y a pas eu d'erreurs
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Si l'utilisateur n'est pas présent dans le tableaux de la requête alors supprime l'utilisateur du tableau du contexte
            foreach ($context->getUsers() as $user) {
                if (!in_array($user, $formArray, true)) {
                    $context->removeUser($user);
                }
            }

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            return $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ? new JsonResponse(['success' => 'Ok']) : $this->addFlash('success', 'Enregistré avec succès.');
        }
    }

    // Envoyez le formulaire de partage de contexte en AJAX ou en standard
    $responseContent =  $this->renderView('context/share.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);

    return $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ? new JsonResponse(json_encode($responseContent)) : new Response($responseContent);
}
```

Benefits of this:

- The GET request can return the same template for regular and AJAX requests.
- The POST request can be regular, or AJAX using `serializeArray()`.
- This allows the form to be validated, and only save changes if each user specified is given a valid ID and exists.
- When validation fails the form template will be returned with validation errors marked. You'd also see if multiple bad user IDs are provided.
- When validation passes a JSON `['success' => "Ok"]` will arrive, though you may want to change the `addFlash()` call to a `redirectToRoute()` if you don't want the form to appear again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adambean for your detailed answer, I'll try to improve my code with your example. However, I've also tried to use .serializeArray() on my $form content, but I get a string like  **"share_context%5Busers%5D%5B%5D=25&share_context%5B…en%5D=vrWCjceU9LVGVrSKyMggRdXNNjeG4KTBDLW0HqIh3aQ"** or  **null** if I use json_decode on my controller.

Comment: That's correct, but you need to read the POST content in a regular "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" way, either with `$request->request->get('users')`, or `$form->handleRequest($request)`. I'd suggest doing the latter as it lets you do form validation much easier. -- I've edited my answer with a controller example.